# BitConverter.GetBytes(some Arguments)

Tags: c#, tcp

I want to send an byte array that contains some arguments. 
but the function `BitConverter.GetBytes()` get only one argument. So I did something but it doesn't look so smart. If someone know how can I do it better so I would happy to learn how. My code :

```
IDMessage = 4; // Length ID Message
byte[] byteToSendLocation = new byte[20];
byteToSendLocation = BitConverter.GetBytes(IDMessage);

IDObserver =2;
byte[] byteToSendIDObserver = new byte[20];
byteToSendIDObserver = BitConverter.GetBytes(IDObserver);

Lenght = double.Parse(LenghtTXT.Text);
Lenght = Lenght * Math.Pow(10, 5);
byte[] byteToSendLenght = new byte[20];
byteToSendLenght = BitConverter.GetBytes(Lenght);

byte[] byteToSend = new byte[100];
Array.Copy(byteToSendLocation, 0, byteToSend, 0, byteToSendLocation.Length);
Array.Copy(byteToSendIDObserver, 0, byteToSend, 20, byteToSendIDObserver.Length);
Array.Copy(byteToSendLenght, 0, byteToSend, 60, byteToSendLenght.Length);

//Send Location Message
client.GetStream().Write(byteToSend, 0, byteToSend.Length);
```

Comment: It would help if you explain more about what you are trying to do.  Send a byte array that contains arguments doesn't make sense.

Comment: What doesn't understand dude ? I have tcp connection between server and client. I sending from the client a byte array. I want to send it smart. As I send it work's fine but it type like an idiot - to to 4 byte array and to copy it to one byte array sounds my too much work, I pretty sure that have easist way. If you have any advice to make it better look I would happy to learn.

Comment: Use BinaryWriter and MemoryStream

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: `BitConverter.GetBytes()` returns a new array. The compiler should warn that all your uses of `new` serve no purpose.

Comment: I have been though about Memory stream and binary writer, I did one project with that, I though have a something better, Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

A helper function would make it a lot shorter:

```
public void SendBytes(MemoryStream ms, byte[] bytes)
{
    ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
}
```

Then your snippet becomes

```
// var client = new TcpClient();
var ms = new MemoryStream();

int IDMessage = 4; // Length ID Message
SendBytes(ms, BitConverter.GetBytes(IDMessage));

int IDObserver = 2;
SendBytes(ms, BitConverter.GetBytes(IDObserver));

Lenght = double.Parse(LenghtTXT.Text)
Lenght = Lenght * Math.Pow(10, 5);
SendBytes(ms, BitConverter.GetBytes(Lenght));

byte[] allBytes = ms.ToBytes();
client.GetStream().SendBytes(allBytes, 0, allBytes.Length);
```

Comment: Eww, that's a lot of network calls.  Combining all the fields into one array and doing one send is better, the question has the right idea.

Comment: Thank's Ben. codemonkey as Ben say's the call to the function takes more time, I search to make it shorter. Thank's any way.

Comment: Added the memorystream in there to collect all data before send.